# Loopback user model instance has no instance methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm fetching a user from a mongo database, but this user that I get, doesn't have any methods, neither all the properties I was expecting. Why would this happen?

This is the code:

```
app.models.MyUser.findOrCreate({where: {email: req.user.email}}, {
      email: req.user.email,
      password: sha1sum(JSON.stringify(req.user)),
      firstName: req.user.displayName
    }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(user.login); //undefined
      res.json(user);
    });
```

This is the code of my model:

```
{
  "name": "MyUser",
  "plural": "myusers",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User.login is a static method, not a prototype method. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.js#L164. You should be able to use `user.constructor.login`.

Comment: Thanks Raymond! Got that working! That piece of code really help me out!